# Magento 1.9 : Value not working on submit button in edit form?

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, custom-button

I created an edit form of custom module, all other fields are working fine but submit button value is not working  my code of button is

```
Matrid_Feedmanager_Block_Adminhtml_Web_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form 
{
 protected function _prepareForm() 
{
 $form = new Varien_Data_Form();


 $this->setForm($form); 

$fieldset = $form->addFieldset('web_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('web')->__('Configuration'))); 

    $fieldset->addField('submit', 'submit', array(
              'label'     => Mage::helper('web')->__('Submit'),
              'required'  => true,
              'value'  => 'Submit',
              'after_element_html' => '<small>Comments</small>',
              'tabindex' => 1
            ));
```

it does not display the button .

Comment: Paste full code of your edit form class

Comment: actually m working on form.php  this is class and function

class Matrid_Feedmanager_Block_Adminhtml_Web_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
  protected function _prepareForm()
  {
      $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
      $this->setForm($form);
      $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('web_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('web')->__('Configuration')));

Comment: Paste it in the question, I mean